# Jekyll: assigning a variable to a post on a for loop

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to create a multilingual website for a company, and, because they have a lot of information, I'd like to include all their information in french and in english **in the same post** like so:

```
en:
   title: "English Stuff"
fr:
   title: "French Stuff"
```

The thing is, in order to use them dynamically in the same layout using something like this,

```
{{ post.[post.lang].title }}
```

I wanted to `assign` a variable when I `for`ed them, to automatically assign the language I wanted on the posts, something like:

```
{% for post in site.categories.yesterday %}

  {% assign lang = en %}

    <li><h2><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.lang.title }}</a><h2></li>

{% endfor %}
```

Is doesn't seem to be working (the titles are not rendered), so I wanted to ask for your opinion. Is the the most viable way to do it? What am I doing wrong and what can I do to improve it?

Comment: Did you already dig in resources merging from a google search like **jekyll internationalization** ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Is there a way to nest a variable?

Comment: @JoostS what do you call nesting a variable ? Maybe you can ask a SO question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to build separate sites on separate domains. It is not DRY, but it is the most simple solution. [Google will tell you the same.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192)

However, if you have a website that requires much changes/evolves over time, the 'not being DRY' part might become frustrating. That would be a reason to use an [internationization plugin](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

This frontmatter in your posts:

```
----
en:
   title: "English Stuff"
fr:
   title: "French Stuff"
----
```

... works with this loop:

```
{% for post in site.categories.yesterday %}

  {% assign lang = en %}

    <li><h2><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post[lang].title }}</a><h2></li>

{% endfor %}
```